# VueJS Print Empty Object Items

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

So I have a project app, in which you can add items. On the initial load, when the user needs to create a new project, I need to print out 5 table rows so user can input information withint those rows. Because those rows are binded to a `project` variable and this project is new, the array is empty so nothing gets printed.

So I guess the question would be how could I "fake" those empty records?

Anybody would know a work around this?

This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<tr v-for="item in project.items">
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
```

**VueJS**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            project: {
                items : []
            },
        };
    },
    created() {
        this.setProject();
    },
    methods : {
        /**
         * Sets Project
         */
        setProject(){
            /**
             * Will check for project id and get it from db
             */
        },

    }
}
```

Comment: You need a table filled by `1,2,3...` initially?

Comment: Just create an array with initial values `[]` => `[1, "", "", ...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to have a separation of concerns here. You should have something that just displays initial project, which has 5 rows with whatever initial values you want the user to see. Then provide some functionality to update or set this as a new project. Separately allow the user to display stored projects from the database.

**Update with example**

After looking at your script it sounds like you're treating your `setProject` method more like a getter than a setter. When someone has defined their data, the setter should do the work of updating or adding that to the database. A `getProject` method retrieves information and displays that.

```js
new Vue({
  template: `<div id="projectContainer">
  <tr v-for="item in project.items">
    <td>{{item.val}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      project: {
        items:[
           {val:'a'},{val:'b'},{val:'c'},{val:'d'},{val:'e'}
        ]
      },
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.setProject();
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Sets Project
     */
    setProject() {
    
    
      // this sounds like a get method rather than a set
      
      
      /**
       * Will check for project id and get it from db
       */
    },

  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I really wanted to avoid something like this, but I guess I cant make something out of nothing. Thank you for your solution